# How to fix problems with russian text encoding in rtf output file in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

My code contains comments in Russian, and when Doxygen is used to create documentation, it has text such as:

```
Classes
•class Rack
Ð¡Ñ‚Ð¾Ð¹ÐºÐ° Ñ Ñ€Ð°Ð¼ÐºÐ°Ð¼Ð¸
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).So it would always help when you specify the doxygen version you use and show the settings in your doxygen configuration file as well as an example of the input you use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change output language to Russian:

Expert -> Project -> OUTPUT_LANGUAGE Russian

[image: Doxygen GUI]